# How to sign a BlockCypher transaction using bitcoinjs

Tags: javascript, blockchain, bitcoin, blockcypher

Im trying to sign a BlockCypher transaction on the bitcoin testnet using bitcoinjs as described [here](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/#creating-transactions) but I keep getting the error:

`{"error": "Couldn't deserialize request: invalid character 'x' in literal true (expecting 'r')"}`

I have searched around and can find no documentation on what the problem is. Below is the code im using to try and sign the transaction.

```
var bitcoin = require("bitcoinjs-lib");
var buffer  = require('buffer');
var keys    = new bitcoin.ECPair.fromWIF('cMvPQZiG5mLARSjxbBwMxKwzhTHaxgpTsXB6ymx7SGAeYUqF8HAT', bitcoin.networks.testnet);
const publicKey = keys.publicKey;

console.log(keys.publicKey.toString("hex"));

var newtx = {
  inputs: [{addresses: ['ms9ySK54aEC2ykDviet9jo4GZE6GxEZMzf']}],
  outputs: [{addresses: ['msWccFYm5PPCn6TNPbNEnprA4hydPGadBN'], value: 1000}]
};
// calling the new endpoint, same as above
$.post('https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3/txs/new', JSON.stringify(newtx))
  .then(function(tmptx) {
    // signing each of the hex-encoded string required to finalize the transaction
    tmptx.pubkeys = [];
    tmptx.signatures = tmptx.tosign.map(function(tosign, n) {
      tmptx.pubkeys.push(keys.publicKey.toString("hex"));
      return keys.sign(new buffer.Buffer(tosign, "hex")).toString("hex");
    });
    // sending back the transaction with all the signatures to broadcast
    $.post('https://api.blockcypher.com/v1/btc/test3/txs/send', tmptx).then(function(finaltx) {
      console.log(finaltx);
    }).catch(function (response) {
   console.log(response.responseText);
});
  }).catch(function (response) {
   console.log(response.responseText);
});
```

It seems this line `return keys.sign(new buffer.Buffer(tosign, "hex")).toString("hex");` is the problem but im not sure on what is wrong.

Answer (score -1):

This question was discussed and answered [here](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/issues/1399). [This post](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/issues/1399#issuecomment-494327826) and [this one](https://github.com/bitcoinjs/bitcoinjs-lib/issues/1399#issuecomment-653073150) are to be looked into in particular.

As far as I understand, according to the issue [respective one](https://github.com/blockcypher/docs/issues/48) was opened at BlockCypher repo. Although its status is still `opened` till this date, current [BlockCypher JS docs respective API description](https://www.blockcypher.com/dev/bitcoin/?javascript#creating-transactions) contains altered version of the line

```
return keys.sign(new buffer.Buffer(tosign, "hex")).toString("hex");
```

with  `toDER()` conversion prior to `toString()`, consequently it looks like this now

```
return keys.sign(new buffer.Buffer(tosign, "hex")).toDER().toString("hex");
```